# PHP mail command

Tags: php, sql

i've run in to a bit of a problem with a PHP mail command
When I go to process it, it just returns an error page.. (not SQL)

Here's my code so far

```
$getdisputes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `disputedetails` WHERE `invno` = '$invoiceno'") or die(mysql_error());
//send email
$to = "".$disputeemail."";
$subject = "Dispute submitted";
$from = "NO_REPLY@noreply.dassdf.com"
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$message1 = "Store ".$username. " has submitted a dispute on invoice number ".$invoiceno;
// foreach line in disputedetails file for that invoice number, add to $message item, desc and 
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($getdisputes)) {
    $message = $message1 + "\n <b>Invoice Number: </b>".$info['invno']." <b>Item ID:</b> ".$info['itemid']." <b>Description: </b>".$info['description']." <b>Disputed Quantity:</b> ".$info['disputeqty']." Reason: ".$info['reason'].".";
}
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Any ideas on what's causing the problem?

Comment: And what is the error? What if there are no results from the SQL, the while loop won't execute and `$message` will never bet set.

Comment: Be more specific, we are not looking at your pc right now.

Comment: This is the most laughable line of PHP I have ever seen: `$to = "".$disputeemail."";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$message1 = "Store ".$username. " has submitted a dispute on invoice number ".$invoiceno;
// foreach line in disputedetails file for that invoice number, add to $message item, desc and 
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($getdisputes)) {
    $message = $message1 + "\n <b>Invoice Number: </b>".$info['invno']." <b>Item ID:</b> ".$info['itemid']." <b>Description: </b>".$info['description']." <b>Disputed Quantity:</b> ".$info['disputeqty']." Reason: ".$info['reason'].".";
}
```

Into:

```
$message = "Store ".$username. " has submitted a dispute on invoice number ".$invoiceno;

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($getdisputes))
    $message .= "\n <b>Invoice Number: </b>".$info['invno']." <b>Item ID:</b> ".$info['itemid']." <b>Description: </b>".$info['description']." <b>Disputed Quantity:</b> ".$info['disputeqty']." Reason: ".$info['reason'].".";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$from = "NO_REPLY@noreply.dassdf.com"
```

There's an error in that line. You need to end it with a ";" semicolon

Like this:

```
$from = "NO_REPLY@noreply.dassdf.com";
```

Comment: Fixed! Thank you aha, I must be tired.

Comment: even worse you must have error checking\display or it would point you right to it.